# How do I ignore UILocalNotification on devices with OS's older than iOS4?

Tags: iphone

I am using local notifications in a app I'm making.

I use this:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (myClass) {
//Local Notification code
}
```

To avoid using UILocalNotifications when not supported.

But my app crashes on launch with this error code:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib"
>   (file not found). dyld: Symbol not
>   found:
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_UILocalNotification   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/FCFFFCB2-A60B-4A8D-B19B-C3F5DE93DAD2/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>
> Data Formatters temporarily
>   unavailable, will re-try after a
>   'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen
>   at this time.)
>   mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough
>   frames in stack.
>   mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough
>   frames in stack.

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to do this is:

```
Class localNotificationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (localNotificationClass != nil) {
    // The UILocalNotification class is available
    UILocalNotification* localNotification =
        [[localNotificationClass alloc] initWith....];
}
```

You can **not** use `[UILocalNotificationClass alloc]` because that will cause **Link Errors** when your code is loaded on an older iOS where the class is not available. And that is exactly what you are trying to prevent.

BTW: Those MobileSubstrate errors are what you get when you jailbreak your phone: an unpredictable/undefined development platform :-)

Comment: Hehe OK. Cant wait to replace my 2g with iPhone 4. No need for sim unlocking and jailbreaking.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind..
I used:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (myClass) {
   //Local Notification code
   UILocalNotification *notification = [[myClass alloc] init];
}
```

instead of:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (myClass) {
  //Local Notification code
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
}
```

and it worked!

Edited to clearify!

Comment: It works on iOS4 but it will fail on older versions. See my answer.

Comment: But on older devices, the IF statement will be false, so the code won't be executed anyway. Or is this not the case?

Comment: Sorry should have been more clear but this is inside the:
Class localNotificationClass = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (localNotificationClass != nil) {
block..

So im basically doing the same as you st3fan. 
@Tom Irving although it is not executed on older devices the [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; part makes it crash..

Comment: You can't do that kind of alloc because like St3fan said, it'll cause linker errors. Instead do [localNotificationClass alloc]